# Checking for date validity in spark sql

Tags: apache-spark

Is it possible to check if a date(yyymmdd) is valid in spark SQL?
I have tried the following:

```
TO_DATE(CAST(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CAST(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(colname, 'yyyymmdd') AS  TIMESTAMP))) IS NOT NULL
```

Thanks,
Bharath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use a dater parser similar to Natty (depending on which language you are using) natty.joestelmach.com

You can create a function which parses and validates date using Natty (or other parser). Then register udf which you can use in your Spark SQL.

```
val isValidDate: String => Boolean =//your validation logic here
sqlContext.registerFunction("dateValidate", isValidDate)
sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM DF WHERE dateValidate(colname)")
```

Comment: This would mean
a) using Scala, not pure Spark SQL, and
b) building a complex validation logic, including things like leap years. Is there really no simpler alternative?

Comment: This is the only option as of now. It may change in future.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

`set spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy=CORRECTED;`

before the select. This policy allows invalid dates to be casted as null.

Hope it helps.